# Typescript generics: How to define properties

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm struggling a bit with generics in typescript and just encountered the following

```
save<T>(data: T): Observable<T> { 
    const created = data.createdTime;
    ...
}
```

The problem here is that typescript tells me that `createdTime` is an unknown property. However, in my case, any `data` object passed to `save` will have a `createdTime` property. What is the correct way to tell typescript that `data` has this property ?

Comment: Is casting to `any` or type with this property a option to you?  `(data as any).createdTime`

Comment: sure, what I sometimes do is `data['createdTime']` but I don't think that any solution which involves `any` is a good solution. It should be possible to be somehow more specific, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `T` extend an interface

```
interface Data {
    createdTime: number
}

save<T extends Data>(data: T): Observable<T> { 
    const created = data.createdTime;
    ...
}
```